# What happen if I ping multicast IP?

Tags: linux, ping

I am learning the ping command and its options.

In that I had one problem. The problem is I don't know how the ping multicast address loop-back works. Because I does not have the multicast address.

So, any one please give me the output for how the ping multicast address loop-back works and what happen if I specify the -L option in that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're going to ask questions on each and every option of the program, you should probably look at its source code: https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping.c and https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping_common.c

Comment: I was learning that source code only. In that I am not able to understand these options. In internet also I was searched for these option. I didn't get the answer for these options. So, only I am asking questions.

Comment: Without looking at the code, I would guess that it suppresses duplicate responses that would be received if the packet was multicasted.

Comment: My guess is also that's only. But I doesn't have the multicast ip to experiment that. So only I am asking the multicast ip pinging output.

Comment: Chances are that your ping requests will never reach a multicast IP.

Comment: Why the ping request will never reach a multicast IP ?